# How can i keep the spawned cubes to be inside the given area?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script generate number of cubes in random positions in a specific given area.
The problem is when some cubes position on the given area border then half of the cube is inside the are and half outside.

Now since the given area is not objects it's just position of walls i'm not sure how to use ray cast for example. Maybe with ray cast i can detect the border/s of the area and then to decide what to do with the cube/s, for example re position them randomly until they will not be on the border but only inside the area ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int numberOfObjects;
    public GameObject objectToPlace;
    public Vector3 newObjectsSize;
    public float spawnSpeed = 0.1f;

    private int wallsLengthX;
    private int wallsLengthZ;
    private int wallsPosX;
    private int wallsPosZ;
    private int currentObjects;
    private List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();
    private GameObject spawnedObjects;

    void Start()
    {
        var wi = GetComponent<Walls>();
        wallsLengthX = (int)wi.lengthX;
        wallsLengthZ = (int)wi.lengthZ;
        wallsPosX = (int)wi.wallsStartPosition.x;
        wallsPosZ = (int)wi.wallsStartPosition.z;

        spawnedObjects = GameObject.Find("Spawned Objects");

        StartCoroutine(Spawn()); 
    }

    IEnumerator Spawn()
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {
            GameObject newObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(objectToPlace);
            newObject.transform.localScale = GenerateRandomScale(newObject);
            newObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(GenerateRandomPositions(newObject).x , GenerateRandomPositions(newObject).y + newObject.transform.localScale.y / 2.0f, GenerateRandomPositions(newObject).z);
            newObject.name = "Spawned Object";
            newObject.tag = "Spawned Object";
            newObject.transform.parent = spawnedObjects.transform;

            objects.Add(newObject);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnSpeed);
            currentObjects += 1;
        }

        var wp = GetComponent<WayPoints>();
        wp.FindMyObjects();
    }

    private Vector3 GenerateRandomScale(GameObject newObject)
    {
        Vector3 newScale = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(5, 100), UnityEngine.Random.Range(5, 100), UnityEngine.Random.Range(5, 10));

        return newScale;
    }

    private Vector3 GenerateRandomPositions(GameObject newObject)
    {
        float paddingX = Mathf.Clamp(newObject.transform.localScale.x, 0, wallsLengthX) / 2f;
        float paddingZ = Mathf.Clamp(newObject.transform.localScale.z, 0, wallsLengthZ) / 2f;
        float originX = wallsPosX + paddingX - wallsLengthX / 2f;
        float originZ = wallsPosZ + paddingZ - wallsLengthZ / 2f;
        float posx = UnityEngine.Random.Range(originX, originX + wallsLengthX - paddingX);
        float posz = UnityEngine.Random.Range(originZ, originZ + wallsLengthZ - paddingZ);
        float posy = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(posx, 0, posz));

        return new Vector3(posx, posy, posz);
    }
}
```

And this is how i make the walls:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Walls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    public Vector3 wallsStartPosition;
    public float width = 0;
    public float height = 1;
    public float lengthX = 2;
    public float lengthZ = 2;
    public float time = 1;

    private List<GameObject> walls = new List<GameObject>();
    private IEnumerator coroutine;

    void Start()
    {        
        for (int i = -2; i < 2; i++)
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(prefab);
            go.transform.parent = transform;
            Vector3 scale = Vector3.one;
            Vector3 adjustedPosition = wallsStartPosition;

            float sign = Mathf.Sign(i);
            if ((i * sign) % 2 == 0)
            {
                adjustedPosition.x += (lengthX * sign) / 2;
                scale.x = width;
                scale.y = height;
                scale.z *= lengthZ + width;
            }
            else
            {
                adjustedPosition.z += (lengthZ * sign) / 2;
                scale.x *= lengthX + width;
                scale.y = height;
                scale.z = width;
            }
            adjustedPosition.y -= height / 2;
            go.transform.localScale = scale;
            go.transform.localPosition = adjustedPosition;
            walls.Add(go);
        }
        coroutine = raiseWall(walls[0], height, time, 0, 100);
        StartCoroutine(coroutine);
        coroutine = raiseWall(walls[2], height, time, 0, 100);
        StartCoroutine(coroutine);
        coroutine = raiseWall(walls[1], height, time, 0, 100);
        StartCoroutine(coroutine);
        coroutine = raiseWall(walls[3], height, time, 0, 100);
        StartCoroutine(coroutine);
    }

    IEnumerator raiseWall(GameObject wall, float amount, float time, float delay, float steps)
    {
        Vector3 position = wall.transform.localPosition;
        float finalHeight = position.y + amount;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        while (position.y < finalHeight)
        {
            float remainingHeight = finalHeight - position.y;
            position.y += Mathf.Min(remainingHeight, amount / steps);
            wall.transform.localPosition = position;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(time / steps);
        }
        yield break;
    }
}
```

In the screenshot you can see the cube on the right part of it is out of the walls area. In this case the walls area is the same size of the terrain 500x500 but the walls could be also 23x45 it's just example.

[image: part]

What i want to do is to avoid overlap between the cubes and to keep them inside the walls area. Maybe i can use ray cast somehow ? And what if instead cubes the spawned objects will be spheres or cylinders ? Ray cast will work on that too ?

Comment: Just a suggestion, i assume you know how to get the area to spawn objects, so you know the positions, why not try to give restriction yourself? Like if the spawn area is squre(for example). And left top is (0,0) right bottom is (10,-10). Your objects will spawn in this area but might collide with walls. So clamp this area make a smaller one inside the original area and use that. Like (1,-1) (9,-9). So now you have a smaller area and objects will not collide with walls.

Comment: @EmreE I thought i'm doing it already with the GenerateRandomPositions method i'm using paddingX and paddingZ and MathClamp  i guess i didn't realy understand how to do it. Could you show me please some example ? And when i'm using a smaller area maybe it's better to calculate automatic the optimal area it should be i mean i can set the smaller area like you said but maybe it's better to consider the cubes X size and then automatic to set the smaller area. Not sure.

Comment: Cannot run your code rn, so what i will say is maybe the same thing you do. I'll try to explain it in more details. You already have the position of the walls and you know the area without clamped, which makes your cubes to collide with walls when instantiated. So you will need a clamped area. When you have uniform object like the cube, (scale is 1,1,1) to make its bottom to touch the ground you make the y axis 0.5. It has 1 unit on y, but it takes the center of the cube. Same thing will do on x axis. So while clamping on x and z axis, _check next comment_

Comment: You need to subtract the **half** value of the x and z while getting the spawn area position. With that when your cubes instantiated, in max they will touch the walls perfectly. You can change the division value (half) to *0.6f* maybe, so your cubes will be really close to wall but will not touch it. I think with this aproach, even if you change the instantiated prefab  to something else, they still will not touch the walls. Hope this is helpfull.